# Firebase security rules to check presence of children

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a firebase realtime database linked to my unity game. My unity game generates a unique GUID and uses it to store anonymised results to a database with the following structure.

```
testDatabase
    users
        09a18248-3402-4495-a8ec-d87fc754b2b0 <- this is the random GUID generated in Unity
            score
            kills
            time taken
        d2ef503c-478c-499b-a52b-eb9b4c3a7e0e
            score
            kills
            time taken
```

I would like to write some firebase rules to validate the presence of the children: score,kills and time taken.

I know I can use something like `"newData.hasChildren(['score', 'kills','time taken'])"` but when I try:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": true,
    ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['score', 'kills','time taken'])"
  }
}
```

It doesn't work. I think it it because I am checking the wrong level of data for the children but I am not sure how to check them at the necessary level.

Comment: Can you try to remove the ".read":false line or set it to true ?

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The issue is when I try to write to the database.

Comment: Security rules don't do anything on their own. Can you edit your question to show the [minimal code that doesn't work against these rules as you expect it to](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?